# Explore the Sharepoint WebServices to integrate with iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sharepoint

I want to integrate sharepoint services with my iPhone app. I do want to explore the web services provided by microsoft share point. From where can i get those services?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am not sure bro, but I guess you have already asked such a question.

Comment: You can find all web services [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Sample code is also provided in that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but you can get the list of services for sharepoint by constructing a url like below.

```
http://yoursharepointhostname/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```